# How to dynamically change color of row in a table when it is load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I am using Angular 1.6.
I have a table:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>QTY</th>
    <th>PRICE</th>
    <th>TIME</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>20.00</td>
    <td>08:08</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>30.00</td>
    <td>08:08</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I needed when the table is loaded, changed the row background color dynamically when current time minus traded time is less than 5 seconds to yellow.

After 5 seconds, the background is changed back to white.

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!

Comment: I put your code into a code snippet. Please add your JavaScript to create a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-style directive here
The ng-style directive allows you to set CSS style on an HTML element conditionally.

And you can use it in your table as follows

Let's say you have trade transaction time in "transaction_time" and the current time in "current_time".

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>QTY</th>
    <th>PRICE</th>
    <th>TIME</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="trade in stockMarket track by $index" ng-style="trade.transaction_time - current_time <=5 && { 'background-color': 'yellow' } || trade.transaction_time-current_time>10 && { 'background-color': 'white'}" >
    <td>{{$index}}</td>
    <td>{{trade.amount}}</td>
    <td>{{trade.transaction_time}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried to put this in a javascript function but it doesn't get call?

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="trade in stockMarket track by $index" ng-style="{changeColor(trade.transaction_time}" >

Comment: does ng-style cannot assign a javascript function?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use the function in ng-style, Have a look at below example

Comment: `
<div  ng-controller="MainController"> 
       <ul id="ColsSettingsList">
        <li ng-style="styleFunction() && {'background-color':'red'}" ng-repeat="listEntry in listEntries" >{{listEntry}} </li> 
      </ul>
    </div>







angular.module('myApp', []) 
.controller('MainController', function($scope, $timeout) {
  
  $scope.listEntries = ["stock1","stock2"];

  $scope.styleFunction = function(index){
    return true;
  }  
  
})
`